# Bypassing switch on electric drill. Which way to wire field coils

Tags: switches

New to the forum. Electrical knowledge and skill is pretty basic.  My question or problem: 
I want to bypass the switch on a cheap (HFT) drill to use as a stationary bench tool. I know that the power will feed the two field coils in series with the brushes. Unfortunately I have the four field coils wires disconnected without knowing where they were before. (all wires are black) Easy to identify the separate coils but dont know if there is polarity or synchronization of the two.
Does it matter which way the field coils are wired? I suspect that it does but not sure how to go about it. I would do trial and error but might short or burn something up. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you get them the wrong way round the motor will go in reverse if the two windings are in the same phase but wrong way round, or the motor will not rotate and may be damaged if the field windings are phased incorreclty.

Answer (score 1):

The two field coils must be connected with each other such that if DC were to be applied, one makes a north pole at the surface of the rotor and the other makes a south pole at the surface of the rotor. You could test that by actually applying a low dc voltage. If you test it with AC, I believe the motor will vibrate rather than turn its the connection is wrong.

If the field coils are connected wrong with respect to the commutator, the motor will turn in reverse.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Charles.  I tried the low voltage DC test but didn't learn anything. I decided to go with 120v. I hooked the power to opposite field leads, ie, bottom on right and top on left. This seems to work. Motor runs at full speed. Does this mean that its correct or is there still a possibilty that the field leads could be backward. I don't want to switch for a test. Thanks again.

Comment: There is not much possibility that it is wrong. Can you check to see if you have the correct direction and the torque required to drill a hole? If the drill completely works, it must be correct.